# How do I get Sum of two Columns with Same Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have three tables: Carrier(C), DropShipper(D) and ShoppingCart(S) with the following schema

Table C

```
c.id(Pk,int,not null)
c.dropshipperid(Fk,int,not null)
c.Prodid(int, not null
c.cost(money null)
```

Table D

```
D.Dropshipperid(Pk,int,not null)
D.Dropshipper(nvarchar(50))
D.Remarks(nvarchar(50))
```

Table S

```
s.cartid(PK, char(36))
s.prodid(pk,fk,int not null)
s.qty(int not null)
```

Here are sample data:

```
c.id    c.dropshipperid  c.prodid    c.cost
--------------------------------------------
1            1             11          100
2            2             11          200
3           3             11          80
4            4             11           70
5            1             6          212
6            2             6          312
7           3             6          412
8           4             6          512


D.dropshipperid   D.dropshipper        D.Remarks
-------------------------------------------------
1                   Airmail               10-25days
2                    DHL                  23-5 days
3                     Fedex                6- 10days
4                       UPS                 4- 5days

S.cartid           s.prodid              s.qty
------------------------------------------------
   xxxx                 11                  2
    xxxx                 6                   2
```

And here is my sql

```
SELECT     D.DropShipper, C.Cost, D.Remarks,( S.Quantity * C.Cost)    AS  SubCost, S.CartID, C.DropShipperID, 
S.ProductID, C.ProductID AS cProductid,  S.Quantity
FROM C INNER JOIN D 
ON C.DropShipperID = D.DropShipperID 
INNER JOIN S 
 ON S.ProductID = S.ProductID
 WHERE (C.DropShipperID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) AND
(S.CartID = @cartid)
```

This is a sample result of my qry:

```
Dropshipper     cost     Remarkd     Subcost     Cartid    Dropshipperid
------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Airmail       100      Text         200        xxxx            1
   DHL           200                   400         xxxx           2   
   Fedex          80                   160         xxxx            3
   UPS            70                   140        xxxx            4
  Airmail         212                 424            xxxx          1
   DHL           312                  624          xxxx            2
   Fedex         412                  824         xxxx            3
   UPS           512                  1024        xxxx             4
```

Here is what I need:

I don Not what the DropShipperID duplicated, ie I need just one set. Then SubCost should be the sum of subcost for each dropshipperID. some thing like this

```
DropShipperID   DropShipper    SubCost    etc
------------------------------------------------
1                Airmail          624
2                DHL               1014
3                Fedex              974
4                UPS                 1164
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 SELECT C.DropShipperID, D.DropShipper, 
        SUM(S.Quantity) AS Quantity, 
        SUM(C.Cost) AS Cost, 
        SUM(S.Quantity * C.Cost) AS SubCost
 FROM C INNER JOIN D ON C.DropShipperID = D.DropShipperID 
        INNER JOIN S ON S.ProductID = S.ProductID
 WHERE (C.DropShipperID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
       AND (S.CartID = @cartid)
 GROUP BY C.DropShipperID, D.DropShipper
```

All the columns in the `select` list should appear in the `goup by` clause, except the columns used with aggregate functions like `sum()`, `max()`, `min()` etc.

In your case columns like Quantity, Cost etc should be used with in `SUM()` function in the `select` list, and should not be used in the `group by` clause.

Comment: Many thanks for your time, when tested your correction, it came up with this err: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetCarrierCost, Line 5
Column 'tbl_DropShipper.DropShipperID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
When I then added the columns it was requesting, it still came up with same repeated D.DropShipperID

Comment: Also, when making small code changes, please *explain* what you did. This answer is nearly useless for anyone but the OP (and, apparently, in this case, also for the OP).

Comment: @siride, what I have done is to add the Group By function  by adopting Nikhil query to replace my earlier query. and it pops up this error: 'D.DropShipperID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause'. And I included D.DropshipperID in the Group By function like so: Group BY C.DropShipperID,D.DropShipperID,D.DropShipper and the Error moved to Qty

Comment: so my final Group By function is like so:  Group BY C.DropShipperID,D.DropShipperID,D.DropShipper,S.Qty,C.Cost. it execute at this point but still the result is not  what I want.

Comment: @NikhilKM, Yes it helped a million times, exactly what i was looking for.